# text datatype convert automatically to number in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2, sqldatatypes

I use Postgres as my database so in my app I use oauth2 the client role after user grant permission to my app so i retrieve the access token from auth server I'm trying to store it in database with column datatype text its inserted as a numbers.

I try varchar it same problem so i try different database MySQL it works fine

[image]

Comment: Sounds like a bug in that oauth library.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name it works fine when i switch to mysql database

Comment: Postgres stores whatever the application sends. It does not change data on its own. So it is a bug/problem in the library that sends that value to the database.

Comment: this is the schema which used 
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/appendix/database-schema.html#dbschema-oauth2-client 
only change the blob datatype to text

Comment: Well if the library expects a "blob" (**binary** large object) then the corresponding data type in Postgres is `bytea`, not `text`. As it expects a binary type it sends the hex encoded value to the database.

Comment: i don't think so i have used the same schema in mysql and change the blob to varchar(500) and it works fine https://imgur.com/EjHvQFr

Comment: Shrug. The library stores a hex encoded binary value. This is not a Postgres problem.